# Как правильно? 1. Не видится края многочисленных армий. 2. Не видится края многочисленным армиям

Tags: управление

Как правильно? Правильно ли это?
1. Не видится края многочисленных армий.
2. Не видится края многочисленным армиям.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не дело так искажать фразеологизм "конца и края нет". С ним используется дательный падеж:

> Конца и края нет многочисленным армиям.